# PHP - Getting child class when executing parent function?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I don't think I am being silly here.

```
class Parent {
  function load($function) {
    if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $function)) {
      // Load Function
    }
  }
}

Class Child extends Parent {
  function foo() {
  }
}

$this->Child->load('foo');
```

The problem is that `__CLASS__` is returning 'Parent'. How do I get it to return Child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question would be use [`get_class()`](http://www.php.net/get_class):

```
if (method_exists(get_class($this), $function)) {
```

but in your case, why not simply use `$this` as a parameter to method_exists()?

```
if (method_exists($this, $function)) {
```

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thank you very much for the help. Will tick in 9 minutes.